# rsync -ahvnz root@ホスト名:/var/www/* /var/www/html/

Tags: linux, rsync

**下記はどういう意味でしょうか？**

```
rsync -ahvnz root@ホスト名:/var/www/* /var/www/html/
```

「ローカルの/var/www/ディレクトリ以下全て」を、「リモートの/var/www/html/ディレクトリ」へコピーするつもりで打ったのですが、

> created directory /var/www/html

と書かれているのに、htmlディレクトリは作成されていません。

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`rsync`で指定するのは「**同期元**」「**同期先**」の順です。オプションや引数の指定方法はコマンドのマニュアルを確認してください(`man rsync`や`rsync --help`など)。

```
$ rsync [option] from dest
```

「ローカル」の`/var/www/`ディレクトリ以下すべてを「リモート」の`/var/www/html/`にコピーするなら、引数の指定は以下の順になるはずです。

```
$ rsync -ahvnz /var/www/ root@HOST:/var/www/html
```

Comment: nを付与していたので実行されなかったのですが(後から気が付きました)、もし実行されていたらどうなっていたでしょうか？　「リモートの/var/www/html/」で、ローカルの「/var/www/」が上書きされていた？　rsyncは失敗上書きしたら終わりですか？　ロールバックは出来ない？？

Comment: まずはマニュアルをよく確認しましょう。`rsync`に限らずユーザの単純な操作ミスをリカバリするような都合のよい仕組みは用意されていません(例えば`cp`で上書きしてしまった場合でも)。リモートとローカルの指定を間違えた場合はどうなるかは、`/tmp`などに適当なファイルを用意して実際に試してみた方が理解できるのではないでしょうか。